# How to get the key of a pushed value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Realtime Database on Android, I want to retrieve this id "-Mb1sSv-FCNr9ElxZIwN".

```java
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration Data1");
mDBListener = databaseReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    mTeachers.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot teacherSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Data DB = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
        DB.setKey(teacherSnapshot.getKey());
        mTeachers.add(DB);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: `for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String keys = childSnapshot.getKey();}`

Comment: Your `teacherSnapshot.getKey()` should be retrieving that key already. Is that no happening? If you step through the code in a debugger, what does `teacherSnapshot.getKey()` show as its value?

Comment: When i run the application there is no errors occur but it's not retrieving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that `KAsr ... dhz1` is the user ID that comes from the authentication process. If so, that UID should also be added to your reference. So to be able to get this id "-Mb1sSv-FCNr9ElxZIwN", please change the following reference:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration Data1");
```

To:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration Data1").child(uid);
```

Meaning that:

```
DB.setKey(teacherSnapshot.getKey());
```

Will set the above key to the "DB" object.

Comment: There is no problem with this step (UID step) i make it before. But, i want to reach to the push key id ("-Mb1sSv-FCNr9ElxZIwN")

Comment: You should use it right now, not before. Have you tried the code I provided you? Does it work?

Comment: yes it work thanx, but i need a way to reach for the push key

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. However, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "reach for the push key"? This is how you read the existing pushed keys from the database. If you need another type of querying, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.